# Start Azure VM for a specified time

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I need to start Azure VM for an hour using powershell cmdlets. I tried using Start-AzVM cmdlet but there was no option to set time.

Is it possible to set time for a VM using az module cmdlets?

The requirement is similar to the Azure sandbox environment which get destroyed automatically after certain time by the time it was started.

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to shut down the VM after a specific time? And probably also deallocate, not just shut down the VM itself?

Comment: I am new to Azure. In my assumption, I thought shutting it down will also deallocate. My only concern is not turn off VM asap to save costs.

Comment: Then make sure you're deallocate it (from azure). Just stopping the VM itself doesn't do that: https://jaychapel.medium.com/how-microsoft-azure-deallocate-vm-vs-stop-vm-states-differ-801deb8e5f2a

Comment: Thanks for the article. It says if we are stopping from powershell/command/portal, it will stop and deallocate by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no commands that can start VM for a specific time. However, there are alternative ways to achieve your requirement.

**WAY - 1**

You can navigate to ***Operations >> Auto shutdown*** from left view pane and then schedule for shutdown considering the time where the VM runs.

[image]

[image]

**WAY - 2**

You can Automate Shutdown or start the tasks for your VM by navigating to your **Resource >> Automation >> Tasks >> Add Task**.

[image]

and now you can Automate for start and shutdown of VM.

[image]

Alternatively, you can make this work using logic apps using [Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurevm/) Connector.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All of the above alternatives suggest shutdown scheduling at a specified time. But, my requirement is to start timer by the time VM is started. e.g. Microsoft Azure sandbox environment works like this only.

Comment: Seems there is no option in az module for specifying time. Accepting it as answer.